# Broken zip when downloading from sharepoint site

Tags: download

I have to download about 200GB of data from a Microsoft 365 sharepoint site on a Mac. The downloaded zip files seem to be broken.

[image]

I have tried downloading smaller folder and fewer set of files at a time etc. I have also tried three different browsers: chrome, safari and edge. Occasionally they work, but most zips do not work. Just searching around, it seems like this issue have been mentioned many times for many years, but I cannot find any solutions.

Is there any solution to make this work?

Update:

Also tried different OS: Mac, Ubuntu and Windows. It doesn't make a difference. File size is probably the main factor. Small files download fine. 1-2 GB files fail 60-70% of the time. 5GB and higher files are corrupted almost 100%.

Answer (score 0):

There are known issues with the standard download functionality. For instance, when an item name contains a + character it will result in a corrupt zip file. It should not depend on the browser because the zip file is generated server-side. Trying to download 200 GB into a single zip file will also be a challenge using the SharePoint download functionality irrespective of any special characters. Another detail to be aware off is the modification date for the files in the zip file: that is set to the download time.

There are 3rd party apps ([list](https://collab365.com/best-document-management-solutions-for-sharepoint/)) that overcome the problem with special characters. I do think you should try to break the 200 GB data set into smaller parts to avoid problems.